# Mongodb not shutting down via --shutdown command

Tags: shutdown, kill, mongodb

i need help with a problem on shutting mongod down gracefully. I'm running mongodb on docker .

i run mongod like with the command :

> mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

and when i close with :

> mongod --shutdown

i get the message :

> There doesn't seem to be a server running with dbpath: /data/db

the message is true , because my db path is not "/data/db"  .

and if i try to shut it down like :

> mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf --shutdown

i get the message:

> killing process with pid: 9

what is the problem ?﻿

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found that if you aren't using the default `--dbpath`, you have to specify it as part of the shutdown.  For example, if you start the `mongod` service with `/Mongo/Data` as the dbpath you have to shut it down with:

```
mongod --dbpath /Mongo/Data --shutdown
```

This works even if you aren't using the default port of 27017.

Comment: I believe this only works on linux.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#use-shutdown

Answer (score 5):

You can just use :

```
pskill mongod
```

Or for some *nix and linux distros:

```
pkill mongod
```

When mongod gets the SIGTERM command(default signal of kill command is SIGTERM), it will shutdown the database gracefully.

You can also check the PID of the mongod process with :

```
ps -ef | grep mongod
```

Then shutdown by:

```
kill <PID of mongod>
```

But **DO NOT use kill -9** for mongod process.

Comment: `pskill` might be available as `pkill` on some machines (including my own)

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that your mongod is running as a service, you can simply try:

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

And `sudo service mongod start` to start again. There is also `status` and `restart`.